# Not able to install JDk in my ubuntu 9.04, getting Error: rpm: not found

Tags: ubuntu, rpm

:~$ !529
Desktop/./jdk-6u21-linux-i586-rpm.bin 
Unpacking...

Checksumming...
Extracting...
UnZipSFX 5.50 of 17 February 2002, by Info-ZIP (Zip-Bugs@lists.wku.edu).
  inflating: jdk-6u21-linux-i586.rpm
  inflating: sun-javadb-common-10.5.3-0.2.i386.rpm
  inflating: sun-javadb-core-10.5.3-0.2.i386.rpm
  inflating: sun-javadb-client-10.5.3-0.2.i386.rpm
  inflating: sun-javadb-demo-10.5.3-0.2.i386.rpm
  inflating: sun-javadb-docs-10.5.3-0.2.i386.rpm
  inflating: sun-javadb-javadoc-10.5.3-0.2.i386.rpm
Desktop/./jdk-6u21-linux-i586-rpm.bin: 255: rpm: not found
Desktop/./jdk-6u21-linux-i586-rpm.bin: 255: rpm: not found
Installing JavaDB
Desktop/./jdk-6u21-linux-i586-rpm.bin: 255: rpm: not found

Done.
:~$ javac
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
 * openjdk-6-jdk
 * ecj
 * gcj-4.3
 * java-gcj-compat-dev
 * gcj-4.2
 * jikes-classpath
 * jikes-kaffe
 * kaffe
 * sun-java5-jdk
 * sun-java6-jdk
Try: sudo apt-get install 
bash: javac: command not found
:~$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the rpm-based installer on a non-rpm-based system.

Ubuntu includes the JRE in it's repositories (if I remember correctly, haven't used it for a while). Something like `apt-get install sun-java6-jre` if I remember correctly.

Alternatively, there should be a second bin file on the download page without rpm in the name. That's just a self-extracting archive that will create a folder containing the jre files. It won't set up the path or anything though.

EDIT: A quick search (for "install sun jre on ubuntu") found this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java - you need to enable the "universe" repository.